# Cancel a running pipeline in circleci

Tags: circleci

How do I cancel a running pipeline in circleci?

Update: When I click on 'Old Experience' there is a button to cancel it, but how is this possible with the 'new experience'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate to a job details, you have Rerun option with a drop-down. You can find option to cancel. Checkout the image.

[image]